# Previewing Properties of Nested ContentViews in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to make the Xamarin Forms previewer on VS for Mac update a BindableProperty at design time without static "design time data", for a visual property element?

In this specific case I have a subclass of a ContentView with a BindableProperty like say "ImageVerticalPlacement", that I want to nest within another ContentView for layout purposes.

However, even setting it like this in the nested ContentView:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference auraMainButton}, Path=ImageVerticalPlacement, Mode=TwoWay}" TextColor="Black" />
```

where auraMainButton is the nested ContentView doesn't change from the default value in design mode when I do something like:

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <controls:AuraButton ImageVerticalPlacement="Below" ImageHorizontalPlacement="Right">
    </controls:AuraButton>
</ContentView.Content>
```

in the main ContentView.

It makes sense to use "design time data" when we're talking about data in a model or a vm, but we're talking about visual properties here rather than model data. This is for making reusable composite UI controls that in some cases may be a ContentView with possibly several nested ContentViews that aren't Controls.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just test it and it seems doesn't supported by the previewer so far. You can share your idea with VS team.

Comment: Thanks @JackHua-MSFT, that's what my tests concluded as well. I tested a number of different ways, posted on the Xamarin forums as well. I started to look into subclassing Layout though, since the properties I want to pass are layout related, and it may just do what I need, since it would be hard from a design standpoint to separate out in a Binding what's a "visual property" versus a "data property", where the latter must be static for design time data.